# Can we execute AWS Athena Commandline from EMR?

Tags: amazon-emr, amazon-athena

I am trying to access AWS Athena from EMR via Athena Commandline

aws Athena start-query-execution --query-string  --result-configuration

But aws help doesn't list Athena.

Where we need to execute the Athena commandline from and how?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste what error you got when you tried below command.

aws Athena start-query-execution --query-string --result-configuration

Did command line didn't recognize the parameter "Athena" ?  Can you please try with smaller case "athena".

Below link has athena CLI documentation

[Athena CLI Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/index.html#cli-aws-athena)

Comment: I was using EMR 5.2.1 and the AWS CLI that came by default with the version of EMR didn't support Athena CLI

Answer (score 0):

Updating the AWS CLI Version on EMR Master node worked

pip install awscli --upgrade --user

Before Update CLI version was

aws --version

aws-cli/1.11.83 Python/2.7.12 Linux/4.4.35-33.55.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.5.46

After Update the CLI version is -

aws --version

aws-cli/1.15.62 Python/2.7.12 Linux/4.4.35-33.55.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.10.61